# How to summon the cultists in terraria xbox 360 edition

Tags: terraria-console

I wanted to beat the game on xbox 360 since I've never done it on old gen ive defeated golem but the cultists wont spawn ive done all the precautions to make sure they did but they wont spawn

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The cultists are not in the Xbox 360 version. The Cultists were added in PC version 1.3 and the Xbox 360 version has not been updated to the console equivalent of 1.3 according to the wiki's [version history](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Console_version_history).

Sad to say but you won't be making it that far on the Xbox 360.